# How to attach a Preference to a particular SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, persistence, sharedpreferences, preference

I am working on implementing the preferences for our application. I know how to display preferences UI and how to read/write values using `SharedPreferences`. In our app, I need to handle two sets of preferences and I would like to ask about this issue, one comment in the Android documents in particular.

The [documentation for Preference.getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getSharedPreferences%28%29) has the following comment under the `Return values` section:

`Returns` The SharedPreferences where this Preference reads its value(s), or null if it isn't attached to a Preference hierarchy.

I would like to ask how it is possible to attach a `SharedPreferences` to a particular `Preference`, be it `EditTextPreference` or others. In other words, how does the persistence code in a `Preference` know that it should store the user input in one particular `SharedPreferences` object and not the other?

To explain my question further with an example, suppose I have the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(file1, mode);
SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(file2, mode);
```

My question is what API I should use so that `prefs1` is used by the `Preference` objects' persistence code and not `prefs2`.

The target is Nexus One, running 2.3.4.

Maybe the answer is obvious but I could not find it after reading the documentation and searching the web. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, how does the persistence code in a Preference know that it should store the user input in one particular SharedPreferences object and not the other?

`Preference` uses `PreferenceManager`'s `getSharedPreferences()`, which eventually routes to `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

You are welcome to create your own `Preference` subclasses that change this behavior, but since the preference screen system may not be designed to handle multiple `SharedPreference` objects, there's a chance that your preference changes might not get persisted.

IOW, I encourage you to reconsider:

> In our app, I need to handle two sets of preferences

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Maybe I am getting it wrong, but if the `Preference` eventually uses `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, then it means there's no way for it to be not attached to a Preference hierarchy (i.e. returning `null`), since there's always a default one that can be retrieved. As for two sets of preference, I meant two distinct set of settings. An example would be a 3D game: One set could be "3D Settings" (or Engine settings). The other would be "Game Settings" (or application settings). To me it doesn't sound that weird that both could be accessed within an app.

Comment: @alokoko: I believe that "Preference hierarchy" here refers to a set of initialized Preference objects in a PreferenceGroup that are collectively attached to a PreferenceManager. Preference != SharedPreference.

Comment: @alokoko: "An example would be a 3D game: One set could be "3D Settings" (or Engine settings). The other would be "Game Settings" (or application settings)" -- those are not two sets of settings. They are one set of settings that you may wish to visually distinguish via `PreferenceFragment`, `PreferenceCategory`, and/or nested `PreferenceScreen` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know a Preference is not a SharedPreference, but now I think I understand what the doc is trying to say: For example, if the code is `Preference p = new Preference()` and then the code calls `p.getSharedPreferences()` without adding it to a hierarchy as you said, then it might (will?) return `null`.

Comment: @alokoko: Your interpretation is correct, as far as I can tell from reading the source code.

Comment: With due respect, semantically they are two sets of settings and we would like to present them as such. `PreferenceFragment` is not available below level 11, and sticking them together via `PreferenceCategory` or nested `PreferenceScreen` objects is ugly (think of putting keyboard settings in the same screen as antialiasing settings or such). In our case, the engine lives in a library project. Maybe adding preferences to that project and somehow using `addPreferencesFromIntent` within the app will work.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you for looking it up for me and confirming my understanding.